# Is COVID-19 vaccination required for travel to India

Tags: india, covid-19, vaccinations

I have a visa for business travel to India (I'm a US citizen), but I have been unable to find a definitive statement of whether a COVID-19 vaccination is required for entry. Most of what I've seen on the consulate website is that the vaccine is suggested, and it appears that as of January 2023 you may randomly be required to provide a negative PCR test when you arrive and show a negative test result.

However, I haven't seen any statement that clearly says whether the vaccine is required or not required. A co-worker says that you need a vaccine and a booster, but I haven't been able to confirm that with any official source. Can anyone provide a link to a government website that shows a clear statement of the requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this document dated December 29, 2022 from the Indian Ministry of Health and Family Welfare (MoHFW), vaccination is preferred, but not required for US citizens.

https://www.mohfw.gov.in/pdf/GuidelinesforInternationalArrivals29thDecember2022.pdf

It does appear that you may be subject to screenings for symptoms and testing, especially if symptomatic, but there is not a vaccine requirement to enter unless you are entering from one of the "high risk" countries. (Currently China, Singapore, Hong Kong, Republic of Korea, Thailand, and Japan)

If the above document is updated in the future, a new version will be posted under resources>travel advisories on [this page](https://www.mohfw.gov.in/).